# Sample a truncated discrete Gaussian distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, sampling, simulation, random-generation

I need to draw **random integers** from a truncated discrete Gaussian distribution. That is, the probability of integer $i$ is:

$$p_i \propto \exp\left( -\frac{(i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$$

for $a \le i \le b$, and $p_i = 0$ otherwise. The missing proportionality constant is obtained from the normalization condition, $\sum_i p_i = 1$. Here $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are real parameters.

Is there a way (package, algorithm, trick, anything) to sample this distribution?

Comment: This is clearly on topic under the [help/on-topic]. I have re-opened.

Comment: If the region to sample is not low probability tail region, the simplest approach is to sample from an untruncated normal and throw away the samples that are out of bounds. When the valid region is a high probability region this should work fine, otherwise you will be throwing away a lot of samples and algorithmic time performance may be bad. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238778/how-do-you-sample-mathcal-n-mu-sigma2-from-a-range

Comment: For the untruncated case you could use accept/reject ("rejection method"); and it turns out to be surprisingly straightforward - if I have this right you can do it by simply rounding a normal with the same mean and variance as the proposal. You need to scale the pmf of that rounded normal so that it's a proper envelope, but I believe the smallest ratio always occurs at round$(\mu)$, so that's straightforward. It would be possible to reduce the rejection rate further by manipulating the proposal slightly but it's unlikely to be worth it.

Comment: Since generating a truncated Gaussian is quite simple (generate a uniform $U$ on $(F(a), F(b))$ and take $F^{-1}(U)$), that should combine with a slight modification of the untruncated scheme above (you need adapt the envelope-scaling-factor $c$ -- in a simple way) to produce a highly efficient method.

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, a distribution on the integers. What is confusing on the question?

Comment: @Glen_b: since the support is made of integers, even accept-reject sounds like overkill. Unless $b$ is much larger than $a$ _and_ they are relatively close to the mean $\mu$.

Comment: @Xi'an yes, indeed for most such cases you can just compute the probabilities and call `sample` -- if numerical issues (like underflow say) are not going to be at issue, you don't actually even need to normalize them (`sample(a:b,n,p=dnorm(a:b,mu,sigma),replace=TRUE)`).

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc: the "truncated Normal distribution" is a misnomer in this question, as this is a discrete distribution with probabilities looking like normal pdfs _at integers_. Hence truncated Normal algorithms do not apply.

Answer (score 2):

I have trouble with seeing where the difficulty stands in simulating from this integer supported distribution. An R code like

```
probz=dnorm(a:b,mu,sigma)/sum(dnorm(a:b,mu,sigma))
```

would work for central values of `(a,b)`, while extreme values would require a bit more caution, e.g.

```
refz=max(dnorm(a:b,mu,sigma,log=TRUE))
probz=dnorm(a:b,mu,sigma)-refz
probz=exp(probz)/sum(exp(probz))
```

Then generating by

```
sample(a:b,n,prob=probz,rep=TRUE)
```

delivers n iid replicas from this Gaussian-like distribution. Note that if `a>mu` and `b>a` are large [in orders of `sigma`] compared with the mean `mu`, this distribution will be undistinguishable from a point mass at `a`.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, if $\sigma$ is not much smaller than 1, then the probability of $a+1$, $a+2$, and so on for at least a few successive integer values will also be significant

Comment: @becko: if $\sigma=1$, $\mu=0$, $a=100<b$, $$p(a)/p(a+1)=10^{44}$$But in any case this is irrelevant for the implementation of the code.